# What is Mysql/Maria "appication info" or "client identification" - and how not to send it with mysqldump?

Tags: mariadb, proxysql

There is a mariadb behind a ProxySQL that I am trying to connect to.

When using "debugging tools" like IntelliJ's Database plugin or DBeaver, it only works when we disable "sending application information".

In IntelliJ it is this setting:

[image]

On DBeaver (disable Client-Identification):

[image]

If we do not disable this identification, we get an error reagarding hostgroups:

```
ProxySQL Error: connection is locked to hostgroup 10 but trying to reach hostgroup 20
```

I'd like to know what this app/client id actually is - and how we disable the same setting
when using mysqldump to that machine (as it results in the same error)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [dbbeaver code](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/commit/4bbcc7273907cfd9a8223c362f0e19a01ea16dae#diff-362830012f3e752ba0166abab8f9a199468b2093c2c02c2fa216be01cddcfaeeR386) that added the disable functionality, there application information is appears to be [connection attributes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_optionsv/#connection-attribute-options).

These options appear to be added to [mysqldump](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/c776f5ac2614e24e64dd06f488ee29716f056c95) 9 years ago so I'm assuming this isn't a regression. There also isn't an option to disable it and I'm finding it hard to believe none of these client utilities haven't been tested with ProxySQL before

This partially look like [ProxySQL issue #2522](https://github.com/sysown/proxysql/issues/2522), but no mention of attributes here. Might be worthy of a new issue.